# Allowing users to login via other networks

Tags: database, authentication, facebook, facebook-graph-api, gigya

I'm currently in the process of dating the data from other networks by the use of Gigya to allow users to login to my site and then post the data with php to my database.

I don't know if this is the best option available as they aren't precise on installing it to post the data etc; they put everything in sub sections on how to do individual things.

I'm curious if there is a custom tutorial on using a different service or making it myself. I've read the API's and developements of some of the site, and facebook using JSON apparently, which I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two elements in your question.

**First, authentication**. There are several services offering you multiple networks authentication, but using several of them for a single user is not as common: you will most likely have to do it yourself. To handle multiple identities in parallel, your server will have to store them and manage the session on its own. Gigya is one authentication solution, there is also two other good ones:

- http://www.janrain.com/products/engage/social-login
- www.clickpass.com/docs (still under development)

**Then, using api.** To do that, you will have to decide what to do and then call the API yourself using Javascript SDKs or server-side ones. Notice the authentication will need to provide you with oauth (most common authentication method) keys to post messages or fetch data. More here:

- developers.facebook.com/docs/api
- developer.twitter.com/doc

Answer (score 0):

One thing worth noting about Gigya. The have a function called "showAddConnectionUI" which basically lets users establish simultaneous connections with multiple social networks. For example, once a user authenticates to your site w/ Facebook, they can also connect with Twitter and Google if you want to allow this. The nice thing is that Gigya manages these identities for you so you technically don't have to implement anything on your side... just call their getUserInfo function and they'll return a collection of identities.

Not sure if that helps... we use this functionality on our site and it works well. Here's the link to showAddConnectionsUI:

http://wiki.gigya.com/030_API_reference/010_Client_API/020_Methods/socialize.showAddConnectionsUI